# Anyone have any experience using Actinic?

Tags: actinic

I'm helping a friend transfer a site to a new server who uses Actinic to run a small catalogue of items.
I've transferred the files over to the new server, but I need to change a few configuration settings for Actinic, as the old server stored files in

```
/public_html
```

But the new one uses

```
/httpdocs
```

Does anyone know which files I need to edit to do this?  I can't get in touch with my friend at the moment as he is on holiday.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to [Actinic](http://www.actinic.com), a company that makes e-commerce solutions? You do not specify which product you are trying to use, but since this is a commercial product, I would suggest simply contacting your vendor or service representative.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a case of changing Network settings in Actinic Application. I'm not sure if you can just copy files from one server and put them into another. It's highly unlikely this will work. Also check if new host is compatible with Actinic. A lot of Actinic websites use secure connections.

Answer (score 0):

Actinic boils down to 2 folders -
CGI-BIN
acatalog
Images and site files go into the acatalog folder
Pear files etc go into the CGI-BIN folder